# Kubernetes immutable labels

Tags: kubernetes, annotations, label

Is there an immutable equivalent for labels in Kubernetes that we can attach to nodes? I want to use labels to identify and segregate nodes but I want to ensure those labels dont get modified.

I was looking at annotations but are they immutable?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like immutable labels or anything like that in Kubernetes. But labels attached to the kubernetes nodes can only be updated by a cluster admin.